# Scaling auto increments

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I am still in the process of weighing the benefit of numeric autoincrement primary keys versus UUID. I use Postgres with Postgis for my backend because I will be doing geolocation based queries.
Performance is an important point because this intends to be a geolocation-based live app, otherwise I would probably care about it less.

For me personally the decision was nearly made. Autoincrement would work best for performant foreign keys and join operations, fast lookups, and a lower cost related to database space in the beginning. I want to use salted [hashids](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids) in my backend to obfuscate my auto-increment primary keys to the client, so I don't need a secondary unique key on my tables for this.

However I always get to the point where they warn against using auto-incremented primary keys in a distributed database system.
Do I need a distributed system? The most honest answer is: I don't know right now, how could I? If the app is not successful, the answer is probably not. If it is, then probably it is.
However, by the time it turns out that I DID need it and that I didn't use a universal key it is too late. Many articles warn against problems related to duplicate keys.

So my question is; how much of a pain is to run the risk using autoincremented keys for the benefit of performance and less space, and to scale to a distributed system over time with auto increments?

My mentor at my current job warned me that premature optimization is evil, BUT that at the same time you shouldn't be naive. Thin line for me here, so what should I do?

Edit: I tagged MySQL as well as I guess that the same applies.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel more comfortable with using `UUID`, and foresee problems with autoincrement in the future, then that is what you should use. The performance impact is negligible. You'll lose a lot more performance because of some other database design issues, definitely not because you're using `UUID`.

For fast lookups you just need to partition the big tables, or cluster them.